# iOS Mobile Config invalid

Tags: ios, configuration-profile

I'm trying to install a mobileconfig file that just block the home button but I have an error : "Invalid profile". I'm on iOS 7.
Here's my xml mobileconfig based on official [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010206-CH1-SW35):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>PayloadContent</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>PayloadUUID</key>
            <string>37BB1711-F1A3-48C3-BCB1-19B6A85394EA</string>
            <key>PayloadType</key>
            <string>com.apple.app.lock</string>
            <key>App</key>
            <dict>
                <key>Identifier</key>
                <string>com.pete.lockhomebutton</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>PayloadDescription</key>
    <string>Disables Home Button</string>
    <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
    <string>Home Button Lock</string>
    <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.pete.lockhomebutton</string>
    <key>PayloadOrganization</key>
    <string>Pete</string>
    <key>PayloadType</key>
    <string>Configuration</string>
    <key>PayloadUUID</key>
    <string>C66415E9-74FE-489A-896C-8AF0F0FE5E9A</string>
    <key>PayloadVersion</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I can't find my error.

Comment: What exactly is the error you are getting? Please post the full error. "Invalid profile" says to me that you aren't using the correct provisioning profile which isn't in here. Just a little inquiry "Home Button Lock" Does your app lock the home button on the device? If so you do realize that this will never make it into the app store. You aren't allowed to mess with the home button.

Answer (score 0):

App bundle identifier:
    `<key>Identifier</key>
     <string>com.pete.lockhomebutton</string>`

Payload Identifier:
`<key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.pete.lockhomebutton</string>`

Both of these cannot be the same.

App Bundle Identifier, this is the identifier of the app which is to be locked.

App lock can be done only if the app is already installed on the device.

Comment: "I believe this app should be already installed on the app." What? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: I suspected this so I didn't downvote as it only needed a quick correction :-)